# Istio Custom Ingress Gateway Works 80 only

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I want to create my own ingress gateway with Istio. Here's my intention:

```
traffic on 4000 > my-gateway > my-virtualservice >  web service (listening on 4000)
```

I've deployed the following YAML:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 4000
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: web
        port:
          number: 4000
```

This **doesn't** work, but changing the gateway port `number: 4000` to `number: 80` **does** work.
Presumably because the `istio-ingressgateway` is open on 80.

Which leads me to believe that this chain is actually:

`traffic on 4000 > my-gateway > my-virtualservice > istio-ingressgateway > web service`

I assume I can fix this by opening 4000 on the `istio-ingressgateway` but doesn't that defeat the point of creating a custom gateway?

I thought the whole point of creating `my-gateway` was to avoid using the `istio-ingressgateway`?

Help me understand! :D

Answer (score 1):

Traffic Flow: Clent -> LoadBalancer(Ingress Gateway Service) -> Ingress Gateway Envoy -> Sidecar Envoy for your application -> Your application.

The ingress gateway is an envoy deployed at the edge of a Kubernetes cluster. All incoming request(HTTP, TCP) to the services inside the cluster arrives at the ingress gateway.The Gateway and Virtual Service kind is what lets you configure Envoy proxy of the ingress gateway.

Creating a gateway object does not really deploy a new gateway,it just configures the same envoy proxy running as the ingress gateway.

Here is a good [reference](https://livebook.manning.com/book/istio-in-action/chapter-4/v-5/)

Comment: I'm confused at the relationship between `istio-ingressgateway` and `my-gateway` which is `kind: Gateway`. Doesn't this mean I'm defining two gateways?

Unless you're saying the logical chain is:
`istio-ingressgateway > my-gateway > my-virtualservice > my-app`

Seems overly convoluted and not documented. Even the official page doesn't mention this > https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/

Comment: As I mentioned the envoy proxy deployed as part of ingress gateway is being configured via gateway.Does not matter how many gateway object you create internally it just configures the envoy proxy and does not deploy a new gateway or envoy.

Comment: If my `Gateway` definition is supposed to reconfigure the `Istio-ingressgateway` service, why did I have to do two things to get this working? 1) Create `my-gateway` and `my-virtualservice`. 2) Edit the `istio-ingressgateway` and add port 3000 to it's definition.

Can you point to any easy to understand docs as I'm not following you or the official documentation unfortunately.

Comment: Oh wait. I think you're saying:
`edge proxy > istio-ingressgateway service > app sidecar proxy > my-app`.

So `my-gateway` is altering the rules of `edge proxy` but then the `ingressgateway` service doesn't accept the incoming HTTP request because the service isn't (by default) configured to accept incoming on `4000` - hence the second rule I mention above? Right?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a reference..please check it